# Maximum thing creation in Eclipse ditto

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-ditto

I'm facing an issue accessing more than 200 things in Ditto.I have created an emulator code which generates things, but ditto supports only 200 things at time. The things are getting created but it's not accessible by search api "api/2/search/things".

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ditto's search endpoint makes use of cursor based pagination, which is quite clearly mentioned in the [documentation](https://eclipse.dev/ditto/basic-search.html#sorting-and-paging-options).

So if you see a `"cursor"` field in the search response, there are more results than fitting in the provided page size (which is 200 by default) and you then request the next page with the query parameter `cursor(<cursor-id>)`